# Testing a CakePHP 2.0.5 Helper which extends FormHelper

Tags: cakephp-2.0

I am creating a CakePHP helper which extends from FormHelper:

```
App::uses('FormHelper', 'View/Helper');
class MyFormHelper extends FormHelper{
    public function wysiwyg($fieldName, $options = array()){
        return parent::textarea('Model.field');
    }
}
```

Here is my TestCase:

```
App::uses('Controller', 'Controller');
App::uses('View', 'View');
App::uses('MyFormHelper', 'View/Helper');

class MyFormHelperTest extends CakeTestCase {
    public $helper = null;

    public function setUp() {
        parent::setUp();
        $Controller = new Controller();
        $View = new View($Controller);
        $this->helper = new MyFormHelper($View);
    }


    public function testWysiwyg() {
        $result = $this->helper->wysiwyg('Model.field');
        $expected = array(
            'textarea' => array('name' => 'data[Model][field]', 'id' => 'ModelField'),
            '/textarea',
        );
        $this->assertTags($result, $expected);
    }
}
```

When I run the test, I have a PHPUNIT_FRAMEWORK_ERROR_NOTICE

```
Trying to get property of non-object
```

I know that the problem comes from my helper:

```
return parent::textarea('Model.field');
```

I have no idea how to fix this.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you want to extend Cake's `FormHelper` and not `AppHelper`, the standard method mentioned in the manual? http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views/helpers.html#creating-helpers

Comment: I extends FormHelper in order to adapt the generated html to my web design. (Adding class, add divs before the input, ...)

Answer (score 0):

To overwrite a HtmlHelper method in Cake 2.0 you can simply:

Create your `OwnHelper` class containing for example a `link` method, which `extends HtmlHelper`, in `AppController` specify:

```
$helpers = array('Html' => array('className' => 'OwnHelper'));
```

via ADmad